# get response in html tag in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-vue

please help me that how can I get data in Html tag like I get in console.loge,
I want to get this `console.log(this.likeDes[0].like_dislike)` in `<span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    likes: 5
  }
})

// You may replace 5 with the likes count.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<link href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">

<div id = "app">
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o"> {{likes}}</i>
</div>
```